# is this python error due to Syntax or program-specific error

Tags: python, text

Newbie to python here, learning it as I go along because our new ERP uses it.

I'm making a custom warning to which I have put together the following output;

```python
'Check the Opportunity stage is at "Prospect-Quoted!"' + ('\n\n If this quote value is different from previous quotes, remember to also update the Opportunity value.' if any([i.id for i in obj.sale_order_ids]))
```

For context, this is when raising a quote against a CRM opportunity, I want to remind the user to update the saved opportunity value if there are other quotes linked to the opportunity (`obj`) from which this is being called.

I'm confident based on the system's Dynamic Values Builder that the section `any([i.id for i in obj.sale_order_ids])` is correct, and the `if` statement is structured the same as others elsewhere in the system, but when attempting to save the custom warning I get an error message saying

> Cannot evaluate Warning. Error: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)

Can someone more experienced tell me, is this a problem with my syntax or more likely to be a program-specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this kind of syntax, with inlined `if`, you must always specify an `else` statement :

```
str1 = 'Check the Opportunity stage is at "Prospect-Quoted!"'
str2 = '\n\n If this quote value is different from previous quotes, remember to also update the Opportunity value.'
result = str1 + (str2 if any([i.id for i in obj.sale_order_ids]) else "")
```